# Why aren't there an infinite number of fields in field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

It is speculated that each particle corresponds to an excitation of its corresponding field, question is why aren't there more fundamental particles hence more fields, what is the limiting factor in other words.

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that other users will know exactly what the issue here is.

Answer (score 5):

You asked three separate questions; I'm not sure exactly what are most interested in, but I would answer your questions in this way:

> Why aren't there an infinite number of fields in field theory?

In fact, there *can* be. [Vasiliev higher spin theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9611024) are an example with an infinite number of fields. Another would be a [Kaluza-Klein compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory).

There are also field theories with a finite number of fields, such as the [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model).

> Does quantum field theory make any predictions regarding the number of existing fields or particles that can emerge?

Quantum field theory is a *framework*, not a specific theory.  The framework doesn't tell you how many fields there should be; there are theories with 1 field, an infinite number of fields, and everything in between.

To determine the number of fields, there are two typical situations: either you are trying to model Nature and you rely on experiment to tell you, or you are trying to answer some theoretical question and are led to some particular theory or class of theories.

> Is space even taken into consideration?

Yes, of course. Spacetime is absolutely central to field theory -- the fields are functions of spacetime (technically operator-valued distributions).